# Laravel Offset not offsetting and/or Skip not skipping

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

i have a database with data and i want to skip/offset the first 3 row.

```
    $data = Data::orderBy('created_at','desc')->skip(3)->paginate(1);
    $data = Data::orderBy('created_at','desc')->offset(3)->paginate(1);
```

both query is returning all result from the start. can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`skip` doesn't seem to work with `paginate`. What you can do is exclude the row by using `whereNotIn`.

```
$data = Data::orderBy('created_at','desc')->whereNotIn('id', [1,2,3])->paginate(1);
```

If you don't know the `id` you can query and use the result.

```
$id = Data::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->pluck('id');
$data = Data::orderBy('created_at','desc')->whereNotIn('id', $id)->paginate(1);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. yes i know the IDs and but your method of getting the IDs are much quicker than mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `paginate()` and `skip()` together. You can do is :

`$data = Data::orderBy('created_at','desc')->skip(3)->take(10)->get();` and update these values skip and take values as per your custom implementation.

If you literally want to skip first 3 rows and never ever use them in pagination, you can do :

```
$dataToEliminate = Data::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->select('id')->pluck('id');

$data = Data::whereNotIn('id', $dataToEliminate)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->skip(3)->paginate(1);
```

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have explored the paginate method from the code and came to know

```php
$data = Data::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(1, '*', null, 2);
```

The `4th parameter`, you need to provide the page number (not the offset).